# Can not compute reject rate in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have 2 measurements OK and ERROR. I would like to compute an reject/error rate using this formula:

```
                      count(OK)
error rate = ------------------------
             count(OK) + count(ERROR)
```

It would be nice to have a continuous query which recalculate error rate every time a new series appears in OK or ERROR measurements.

How is it possible to do it in InfluxDB?